# System hung when a device with exFAT is plugged

Tags: 14.04, exfat

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit version and it worked well until I used `apt-get` to install support for exfat file system.  (`apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`).

The installation appeared successful but when I plugged in a 64GB Micro SD card formatted exfat, my system hung and only a power off would restart it.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong or show me a solution to this, please? (I know the first problem was to use a windows system at all!)

As you suggested David - I checked the log and found a batch of '00' where data should have been.  This happens every time even after uninstalling and reinstalling the program.

Comment: Next time this happens write down the time. After a reboot you can inspect `/var/log/syslog` for entries relating to that time and include them in your question. Also, make sure that the file system doesn't have any error with Windows' `chkdsk /f` if you can.